# Render HTML after each iteration in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slowly increase the font size of text on a web page.  The code I have in place does work, however the new HTML/CSS does not render after each iteration of the loop and will just display the 100px size text when it's all done.  To make the text look like it's slowly zooming in I need to do that.  The javascript is below as it is being used from a separate file.  Here's what I have...

```
<p class="game-title" style="font-size:50px">Test</p>

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function increaseSize() {
    $('.game-title').css('font-size', parseInt($('.game-title').css('font-size')) + 1 +          "px");
}

        while (parseInt($('#text').css('font-size')) <= 100){
            sleep(1000);
            increaseSize();
        }
```

Comment: Your `sleep()` is blocking the main thread,which means nothing will be done until it's free. That's why JS doesn't have a `sleep` function. I'm sure if you search around, you'll find the proper asynchronous ways to do what you want.

Comment: Please never write a "sleep()" function like that. You're passing the time burning up the client computer's CPU and battery. This is what `setTimeout()` is for.

Comment: Where is the HTML element for `$('#text')`?

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and / or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) are your friends

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Both CSS and jQuery have methods for doing animations and transitions. I suggest you use one of them.  CSS is better for battery usage and smoother playback, while jQuery can be used if you need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS (sample http://jsfiddle.net/X3crE/2/):

```
<p class="game-title">Test</p>
<style>
.game-title { font-size:50px; transition: 2s; }
.game-title.large { font-size: 100px; }
</style>
$('.game-title').addClass('large');
```

Using jQuery (sample http://jsfiddle.net/X3crE/):

```
$('.game-title').animate({'font-size':'100px'},2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do in asynchronously. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/W3e4V/).

```
function increaseSize() {
    var title = $('.game-title'),
        size = parseInt(title.css('font-size'))

    title.css('font-size', '+=1');
    if(size < 100) {
        setTimeout(increaseSize, 1000);
    }            
}
```

And plz **never** block main UI thread.

Comment: `$('#text')` should be `$('.game-title')`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are blocking the browser from rendering in your `sleep` method. Browsers are single threaded, except your are using webworkers and this single thread is also responsible for rendering. You can just see the result, because your are blocking the browser from rendering with your sleep method.

Try to create something like that:

```
var size = 10, big = 20, step = 1;

function setFontSize(s) {
    /*code to resize*/
}

function increase () {
 if (size < big) {
    setFontSize(size);
    size += step;
    window.setTimeout(increase, 1000);
 }
}

increase();
```